# config of multidimensional array on Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Which considers first? [col][row] or [row][col]?

```
public class multiDiArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char [][] name = {  

                {'A','B','C','D','Q'},
                {'E','F','G','H','R'},
                {'I','J','K','L','S'},
                {'M','N','O','P','T'},
                {'U','V','W','X','Y'}

        };

        System.out.println(name[1][0]);  // shows J
        /*System.out.println(name[0][0]);  // shows A
        System.out.println(name[3][1]);  // shows N
        System.out.println(name[3][1]);  // shows N
        System.out.println(name[0][0]);  // shows A  
        System.out.println(name[3][4]);  // shows T
        System.out.println(name[2][0]);  // shows I
        System.out.println(name[3][1]);  // shows N
        */

    }
}
```

Comment: all your cases satisfying [row][col] except the first one, can you recheck your array

Comment: Well, it doesn't show J, it shows E. So your situation is not reproducible. Could it be that you forgot to save the file or re-compile it after a test that produced J?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[row][col] is the correct order, so [0][0] = A, [1][0] = E, [0][1] = B

```
0 {'A','B','C','D','Q'},
1 {'E','F','G','H','R'},
2 {'I','J','K','L','S'},
3 {'M','N','O','P','T'},
4 {'U','V','W','X','Y'}
    0   1   2   3   4
```

I hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: How do you explain this: "System.out.println(name[1][0]);  // shows J" ? It should show 'E'.

Answer (score 0):

By defualt in java Multidimensional array is arrays[column][row].

And even you can manipulate with order in your code

for example you would like to print row then column .